# IMAP login to Gmail server via CLI fails

Tags: command-line, ssl, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to log into my Gmail account manually using OpenSSL in my terminal. But for some reason, Gmail doesn't authorize my login even if the password is correct.
Here's a rundown of my terminal:

```bsh
openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.googlemail.com:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
.......
# Some stuff displayed here
.......
* OK Gimap ready for requests from <my-ip> f75mb26659817ybg
01 login username@gmail.com password
01 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

Why does it fail? Also, I am a beginner with this and am very curious about doing this, therefore a few article suggestions regarding this would be great.

> I tried searching for related articles myself but was unable to do so even after pages of searching.

Comment: I was able to achieve my goal using Gmail API and OAuth2 authorization. Took quite some bash scripting. Here are the results: [My Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/ahxrbe/unread_email_counter_i3blocklet_for_gmail_using/). I'm still not solving this question as marked because the solution I've found is just a workaround.

Comment: how about adding the solution specifics you found from that post as an answer with more and precise detail? I think that'd be much better than this comment with just the link and you saying "check the answer here" and then a year down the road that link gets trashed, etc. If you post the content and the link as an answer, it will be much much better and helpful to that that also need that same answer but quicker if you share the specifics that are to the point about the solution you potentially found. Choo Choo!!!

Comment: Second that. Workarounds are completely acceptable answers, especially when a direct solution is not available.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It's been quite some time and I have provided my own workaround below since this question would have had received an answer if it was meant to by now. Please have a read and tell me if I need to add something more.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I've added the workaround as an answer. Please have a read and tell me if it needs something more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tries, it seemed to me that Gmail has dropped support for basic IMAP login as it is "less secure". So I ended up using OAuth2 for the authentication process. I also found that my goal, to fetch unread email count, could also be achieved using Gmail API afterwards. To implement it, I wrote a script in bash.

### Here's what the script does in summary:

- [Create credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#creatingcred) for a client with access to the Gmail API and necessary scopes set.
- Use those credentials to generate an authorization code for the user's account.

  > During this, the terminal opens a *user consent* webpage which asks the user if he/she authorizes the client or not. Once authorized, the *OAuth2 authorization code* is sent to `localhost` at the specified port(I used 5000) which is then caught by the TCP listener, which the script runs in background temporarily, and stored.
- Once the authorization code is stored, generate the API access token and store it somewhere for use.
- Make curl requests like this to access the API:

  ```bsh
  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <the access token>" <the request>
  ```

### Here are the relevant links:

- [Gmail Unread Mail Counter Script](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/i3blocklets/blob/master/gmail): This script uses the refresh token stored in a file to access the API through a new access token generated using the refresh token.
- [OAuth Access Token Generator Script](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/i3blocklets/blob/master/resources/gmail/genToken.sh): This generates an access token and refresh token and stores them in a file locally.
- [Their Documentation](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/i3blocklets#gmail-block)

Comment: Now this is the way you are supposed to write an answer and keep it clear and concise and with clear links plus the nice formatting as well. Nice answer!! Keep up the good work!! +1

Comment: I wrote something similar but used perl and jq. See https://github.com/jay/curl_google_oauth

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Make sure to [Let less secure apps access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) though since otherwise plain login (user + password) might not work.

Comment: Isn't there some way to make this approach more secure instead of making my account more vulnerable by allowing access to less secure apps? Saying this because I don't have a  GSuite account and hence can't enable less secure apps to log in.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma: sure, you can use the more secure authentication method: SASL XOAUTH2. But this means that you will not be able to just use `login user pass` in IMAP but that the process is more complex (and more secure). See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol#the_sasl_xoauth2_mechanism) for details. You might also use [application specific passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I don't mind complexity since it gives me the opportunity to get to know more. I'll go over it and post my updates here once done.